# How to call response in laravel

Tags: laravel

```
Response {#695 ▼
  +original: array:2 [▼
    "success" => true
    "data" => array:2 [▼
      "d" => 5
      "ss" => "3.0"
    ]
  ]
  +exception: null
  +headers: ResponseHeaderBag {#691 ▶}
  #content: "{"success":true,"data":{"d":5,"ss":"3.0"}}"
  #version: "1.0"
  #statusCode: 200
  #statusText: "OK"
  #charset: null
}
```

How can I access `ss` value `echo $rating_data['data']['ss'];die;`

it says Cannot use object of type `Illuminate\Http\Response as array` please suggest

Comment: you have printed output using `dd()` try using json so that it will be readable

Comment: json what encode decode ?

Comment: try this statement `response()->json($response);`

Comment: $json_string = json_encode($data, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
{ "original": { "success": true, "data": { "d": 5, "ss": "3.0" } }, "exception": null, "headers": { } }

Comment: where do you want to use this json?

Comment: outside of laravel you can `var_dump()` non-strings. Inside `dd()` is a great option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use dd() to print result in readable formate:

```
dd(json_decode(json_encode($ResponseData), true));
```

and return response :

```
return response()->json($ResponseData);
```

Hope this may help you!